# Use ExecutorService or Similar to Queue Tasks to be Completed in Order?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have three tasks: download .zip from internet, unzip file, then swap out a local file with the unzipped file. I can't block the main thread, as it's being used by the server, but I need these three tasks to complete in order. Is there a way to use ExecutorService or something similar to queue these tasks so that one completes after the other without blocking on the main thread?

Comment: Can you not just put those operations in sequence in a `Runnable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single thread executor. The services below will run in parallel to the main thread, and the three tasks handled by `e2` will run sequentially.

```
ExecutorService e1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ExecutorService e2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
e1.execute( new ExpressTask() );
e2.execute( new SequentialTask("Part-One"));
e2.execute( new SequentialTask("Part-Two"));
e2.execute( new SequentialTask("Part-Three"));
e1.shutdown();
e2.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run a thread:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
       task1.run();
       task2.run();
       task3.run();
    }
}.start();
```